# Connection issue to Hive with Talend

Tags: hive, talend

I'd like to connect through Talend Open Studio for Big Data (7.2.1) to Hive.

Connection seems OK if I just use standard properties, but if I try to use some advanced properties I have an issue :

For example if I try to set the namenode URI through the dedicated checkbox/field :
[image]

Then I have an error during execution : [image]
There is a syntax error concerning a dot that is set inside the generated code by Talend :

```
System.setProperty("fs.default.name", "mynamenode");
```

I have tried without success to escape the "." character. What can I do to use properties in my tHiveConnection ?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a URI, not a machine name.so it should be like this:  hdfs://mynamenode:portnumber

Comment: Yes , "mynamenode" is just an example. I have actually tried with a correct URL. But the problem is still the same , as it is related to the name of the property itself ("fs.default.name") and not the value of it.